# Check if all inputs are empty (have no value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, each

I am just trying to throw together something quickly that checks to see if any of the inputs in my form are empty.
I am trying this:

```
var isEmpty = true;
$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() === ""){
        isEmpty = false;
    }
});
alert(isEmpty);
```

but it keeps alerting **true**.
If I do this:

```
$('input').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val();
});
```

it will alert for every input field I have...
Why is it not returning false if I have an empty input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small snippet to check for all your **text** `inputs` are empty:

```
var isEmpty = $("input[type='text']").filter(function () {
    return this.value.trim();
}).length === 0;

console.log( isEmpty );   // boolean true/false
```

***[jsBin playground](http://jsbin.com/geriter/7/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

P.S: For `checkbox` and `radio` the game is simpler:

```
var isUnchecked      = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length === 0;
var isRadioUnchecked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").length === 0;
```

#### BONUS: `:blank` custom selector (appliable to any element)

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  blank: function(e,i,m) {
    if(/input|textarea/i.test(e.tagName)) {
      if(/checkbox|radio/i.test(e.type)){
        return !e.checked;
      }else{
        return !e.value.length;
      }
    }else{
      return !e.innerHTML.trim();
    }
  }
});


$("div:blank").css({outline:"2px solid red"});
$("input:blank").css({outline:"2px solid red"});
$("textarea:blank").css({outline:"2px solid red"});
   
$("div:not(:blank)").css({outline:"2px solid green"}); // how cool is that? Using :not
```

```css
*{margin:5px;padding:2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div>Example using :not(:blank) selectors</div>
  
<input type="text" value="abc">
<input type="text" value="">
  
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
  
<input type="radio" checked>
<input type="radio">
  
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea>abc</textarea>
```

On standard elements like `<div>` or `<p>` etc, `:blank` acts differently from jQuery's  `:empty` selector cause notice the spaces and newlines:

```
 <p>

 </p>
```

and see the results:

```
$("p:blank").length // 1 (found one blank paragraph)
$("p:empty").length // 0 there's no empty paragraph (since the newlines/spaces)
```

---

**Back to your question :)**

Since you're **looping all your elements**, currently you're only setting the value of `isEmpty` to the **last element in loop** - value.
You could assert your boolean flag into the `if` like:

```
var isEmpty = false; // start with a falsy presumption
$('input').each(function(){
    // as long as `isEmpty` is `false`
    if(isEmpty===false && $.trim( this.value ) === "") {
        isEmpty = true;
    }
});
```

also, checking for *emptiness* doing `=== ""` makes more sense to return `true`

otherwise the other way around is inverting your negation

```
var isEmpty = true; // start with a truthy presumption
$('input').each(function(){
    if(isEmpty && $.trim( this.value )){
        isEmpty = false;
    }
});
```

**Here's a live example:**

```js
var isEmpty = true; // start with a truthy presumption
$('input').each(function(){
    if(isEmpty && $.trim( this.value )){
        isEmpty = false;
    }
});

alert(isEmpty); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="something">
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: that was my bad, I fixed the question. I do have .val() in my code.

Comment: @Kalkrin edited. Yet still untested but hope it makes sense.

Comment: I got it working, thank you for your input and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is outside the loop , so it will alert only the final value.Hope this below code is useful

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id=" " value="rdrdr"/>
<input type="text" id=" " value=" "/>
<input type="text" id=" " value="xdxd"/>
<input type="text" id=" " value=" "/>
```

**JS**

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var isEmpty = true;
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
        isEmpty = false;
    }
    console.log(isEmpty)
});
```

[Chexk here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hL4xdb5c/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're checking:

```
if($(this) === "")
```

but `$(this)` is a jQuery object, which is never identical to the empty string. Perhaps you intended to write this?

```
if ($(this).val() === "")
```

Comment: that was my bad, I fixed the question. I do have .val() in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the val() for every input so remember obtain the value to be compare:

```
if ( $(this).val() === "" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the variable first, not containing any value. Then place a value when it is a certain scope and call it.

```
var isEmpty;
    $('input').each(function(){
      if($(this) === ""){
        var isEmpty = false;
        return isEmpty;
        alert(isEmpty);
      } else {
        var isEmpty = true;
        return isEmpty;
        alert(isEmpty);
      }
    });
```